# iOS: Background image navigation bar mail compose view controller

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Since iOS 5 it is easy to customize the background image of `UINavigationBar`, but it seems that there is something that I am missing when it comes to setting the background image for `MFMailComposeViewController`. I use the following snippet to set up an instance of `MFMailComposeViewController`.

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])) {
    // Initialization
    MFMailComposeViewController *vc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

    // Navigation Bar
    [[vc navigationBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_top"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    // Configuration
    [vc setMailComposeDelegate:self];

    // Present Mail Compose View Controller
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

While the bar button items are properly skinned, the navigation bar of the mail compose view controller is not. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 2):

Just add some code in your "myAppDelegate.m" as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueBarBG.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    ...
}
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : refer [custom-background-for-uinavigationbar](http://www.mladjanantic.com/setting-custom-background-for-uinavigationbar-what-will-work-on-ios5-and-ios4-too/) link.

I think u might have **given wrong image name**: navbar_top it might be navbar_top.png or navbar_top.jpg

U can try this:

```
if([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) //iOS >=5.0
{
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_top.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Comment: This is not an option in the current situation since I do not want all the navigation bars to have the same background image. I have tried [UINavigationBar appearance] in the past and this does render the correct result, but, as I said, I cannot use this approach as not all navigation bars have the same background image. Also, since I am targeting iOS 5+, it is not necessary to specify the file name extension.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017382/ios-uiappearance-appearancewhencontainedin-issues add your image in setBackgroundImage:image instead nil

Answer (score 0):

You can do this because MFMailComposeViewController class inherited from

```
UINavigationController : UIViewController : UIResponder : NSObject
```

But go through the apple documentation. Apple wont allow to do so.

**Important**

The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your    application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.

FOR MORE INFORMATION [MFMailComposeViewController_class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you still want to implement then this might help you
[changing-the-navigation-bar-with-MFMailComposeViewController](http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/changing-the-navigation-bar-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/)

Comment: I am not sure if this is entirely true since using [UINavigationBar appearance] to customize the navigation bar application wide does customize the navigation bar background of MFMailComposeViewController.

Answer (score 0):

after u present the controller

```
// Present Mail Compose View Controller
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

add the image as an imageView like this

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navbar_top.png"];
UIImageView * iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,42)];
iv.image = image;
iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[[[vc viewControllers] lastObject] navigationItem].titleView = iv;
[[vc navigationBar] sendSubviewToBack:iv];
[iv release];
```

but I believe there is some kind of protection that came with iOS4.

It is clearly stated here that you MUST NOT change the interface provided by Apple.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Important: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.

i have searched the forums and some have got their app rejected, so i guess u should refrain urself from doing this.

hope it helps. happy coding :)